# How to create an empty mutable list in python, so that list item can be added later?

Tags: python, list, tuples, immutability, mutable

I want to create an empty list in python so that I can add items into it later by a function. But when I tried to add items into it through function it showed me "TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly". Why am getting this?

```
page = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, " \
       "or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't " \
       "anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, " \
       "making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence " \
       "structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, " \
       "or non-characteristic words etc."

find_word = "the"
word_positions = []
pos = 0

while page.find(find_word) != -1:
        word_positions.append(page.find((find_word, pos)))
        pos = pos + len(find_word)

print(word_positions)
```

Comment: `page.find((find_word, pos))` You are getting this because you pass a tuple to `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `word_positions.append(page.find((find_word, pos)))`, `page.find((find_word, pos))` passes a `tuple` to `page.find`, but `page.find` is expecting the first argument to be a string (the word to find).  You want:

```
page.find(find_word, pos)
```

(notice that I dropped one set of parenthesis)

---

There are some other logic errors in your code as well.  First, your loop might go on forever because `page.find(find_word)` will always find something if it found something the first time.  Change it to:

```
while page.find(find_word, pos) != -1:
```

Second, you'll end up with duplicates in your list from:

```
pos = pos + len(find_word)
```

The number of found words has nothing to do with what position you expect to find them at.  You probably want:

```
pos = word_positions[-1] + 1
```

since you want to continue looking immediately after the last found item.

---

Finally, this task can also be accomplished almost trivially using `re`.  (You don't even have to write a regular expression since you're looking for a literal word!):

```
import re
word_positions = []
for match in re.finditer(find_word, page):
    word_positions.append(match.start())

print(word_positions)
```

Note that this can also be written in 1 line as a list-comprehension:

```
word_positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(find_word, page)]
```

Comment: I dropped one set of brackets. But it is not adding position of the word to list (word_positions)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import re

page = "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, " \
       "or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't " \
       "anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, " \
       "making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence " \
       "structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, " \
       "or non-characteristic words etc."

find_word = "the"
word_positions = []
pos = 0

for match in re.finditer(find_word, page):
    word_positions.append( (find_word, match.start()) )

print(word_positions)
```

It outputs:

```
[('the', 68), ('the', 273), ('the', 317), ('the', 341), ('the', 371), ('the', 443), ('the', 471), ('the', 662)]
```